# Decorator with View

Tags: php, view, design-patterns, decorator

How to apply a decorator in a structure views, knowing that only a single view is responsible for executing the block of code to render the template? as:

```
<?php
          class View {

                 public function render ( $template ) {
                        printf ( 'Rendering template %s' , $template ) ;
                 }

          }

          class MemberView { }

          class AdministratorView { }


          $Admin = new MemberView ( new AdministratorView ( ) ) ;
          $Admin->render ( ) ;
```

In this case, I am rendering an administrator, but when going through the drivers, will acquire and the basic functions that every member has reached the view and perform to show panels, or things that only administrators can see, but in logic, a administrator is also a member .. so the structure has to be made​​, applies to moderators, global moderators ..

My question is that of how to apply the decorator in this case ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we managed to solve the problem .. the solution:

```
<?php

          class View {

                 public function render ( $template ) {
                        printf ( 'Rendering template %s' , $template ) ;
                 }

          }

          abstract class ViewDecorator extends View {

                 protected $view ;

                 public function __construct ( View $view ) {
                        $this->view = $view ;
                 }

          }

          class MemberView extends ViewDecorator {

                 public function render ( ) {
                        $this->view->render ( 'Member' ) ;
                 }

          }

          class AdministratorView extends ViewDecorator {

                 public function render ( ) {
                        $this->view->render ( 'Administrator' ) ;
                 }

          }

          $ADM = new MemberView ( new AdministratorView ( new View ( ) ) ) ;
          $ADM->render ( ) ;
```

The output: Rendering template **Administrator**

If I remove the rendering of the administrator.

```
<?php
          $Member = new MemberView ( new View ( ) ) ;
          $Member->render ( ) ;
```

The output: Rendering template **Member**